# Sublime Text 3: Settings for NodeJS Build System

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, sublimetext3

I downloaded the **Nodejs** plugin, using **Package Control** in **Sublime Text 3** editor.
I can't config the original settings file, without setting a different javascript build system.

### GitHub

https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs

### ..\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Nodejs.sublime-settings

```
{
  // save before running commands
  "save_first": true,
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe", 
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": "C:\\Users\\fraballi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm",
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
  "node_path": false,

  "expert_mode": false, 

  "ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```

### Console error

```
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node', 'C:\Users\..\the\path\to\file\js']]
[dir: C:\Users\..\the\path\to\file\js]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin;c:\xampp\php;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;\exercism;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Users\fraballi\AppData\Roaming\npm]
```

Comment: How is `taskkill /F /IM` getting added to the `cmd`?

Comment: I previously set "cmd" option in the file, for general build-systems in sublime; but I got notice of that and improve the question. By the current way, the console doesn't locate the command, the output is different to this, nothing is shown, but still doesn't work.